# Manage User Data on Django HTML with passing data

Tags: django

I'm doing small example project by Django. I'm making a Blog.

in views.py I could render index.html with posts by passing posts dictionary onto third argument of render function as below.

```py
def home(request):
    posts = post.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts':posts})
```

By doing this, I could use posts data on HTML as below

```
{% for post in posts %}

<a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <h4>{{ post.id }}</h4>
</a>
<p>{{ post.date }}</p>
```

However, when my instructor taught me how to implement login/logout function, I discovered he didn't pass the user data but he could manage 'user' data on HTML as below

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{{ user.username }}님
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

```py
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

How is `if user_is_authenticated` could be rendered successfully on HTML without passing 'user' data on views.py?

Comment: after user authenticate on a django site, django store some authenticator of the user in his browser, thats how django can authenticate user without passing him in views. You can see it on this screenshot, it is google chrome https://ibb.co/CHZjMvk

Answer (score 0):

The `User` context object is provided to the template by the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor defined in your settings file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/context_processors/